# Combination of rows from a single table

Tags: sql, join

I am design a windows application that computes Apriori Algorithm. 
I want to create a combination of rows from a single table.

(Tablename=L1)

---

```
ItemSet
------
1

2

3
```

---

The table I want using a SQL Query

```
ITEMSET (Table name= C2)
-------
1 2

1 3

2 3
_____
```

---

Order is not important.

Thank You In Advance. 
I guess it can be done using Joins but I cannot figure out How!

Comment: You should try to make this work by yourself first, and then if you're still having problems, post the SQL to your question.

Comment: Will the rows always be no.s ? or will chars be added?

Comment: @mjuarez I tried but couldn't find out and searched many post related to Combination but couldn't figure it out

Comment: @Sayka nope just numbers

Comment: can u use procedures?

Comment: Can be done with sql procedure

Comment: I am using Visual Studio so anything that would work there is fine by me. I found a example for a table 'colors' SELECT a.color, b.color
FROM colors a
CROSS JOIN colors b
WHERE a.color != b.color

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [cross join](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php) like

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
CROSS JOIN table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the actual application of Apriori Algorithm but works for the above combo.

```
Select Val1, Val2 From L1
Join (
Select L1.Val1 As Val2 From L1)L2
ON Val1 <> Val2 And Val1 < Val2
```

Assuming Val1 As the Column Name

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from L1 as t1 JOIN L1 as t2 on t1.ItemSet < t2.ItemSet
order by t1.ItemSet, t2.ItemSet
```

(Using ItemSet as L1's column name...)